# How to Setup Session Fixation in Spring Boot 3?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to migrate and adapt Baeldung's [Spring Security Registration](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration) project to use latest Spring Boot 3.0.2. The [`SecSecurityConfig.java`](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/blob/master/src/main/java/com/baeldung/spring/SecSecurityConfig.java#L76-L118) uses `sessionFixation().none()`.

```java
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(PUBLIC_PATHS).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/invalidSession*").anonymous()
            .antMatchers("/user/updatePassword*").hasAuthority("CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE")
            .anyRequest().hasAuthority("READ_PRIVILEGE")
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage.html")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
            .authenticationDetailsSource(authenticationDetailsSource)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .invalidSessionUrl("/invalidSession.html")
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
            .and()
        .sessionFixation()      // <---- This part here
            .none()                 // <---- This part here
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(myLogoutSuccessHandler)
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout.html?logSucc=true")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .rememberMe()
            .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())
            .key("theKey");
    return http.build();
}
```

While this format works, I kind of find it difficult to follow the configuration setup, and hence I transformed it to use the overloaded `Customizer` methods instead. Here is how it turned out to be.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .csrf(request -> request.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request ->
                request
                    .requestMatchers(PUBLIC_PATHS).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/invalidSession*").anonymous()
                    .requestMatchers("/user/updatePassword*").hasAuthority("CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE")
                    .anyRequest().hasAuthority("READ_PRIVILEGE")
            )
            .formLogin(request ->
                request
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage.html")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                    .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
                    .authenticationDetailsSource(authenticationDetailsSource)
                    .permitAll()
            )
            .sessionManagement(request ->
                request
                    .invalidSessionUrl("/invalidSession.html")
                    .maximumSessions(1)
                    .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
            )

            // sessionFixation.none ???    <---- How this can be configured

            .logout(request ->
                request
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(myLogoutSuccessHandler)
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout.html?logSucc=true")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .permitAll()
            )
            .rememberMe(request ->
                request
                    .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())
                    .key("theKey")
            )
            .build()
    ;
}
```

The only part that I am unable to configure is the `sessionFixation` part with the `Customizer` setup. Can somebody point me out how to configure it?

Comment: `sessionManagement(configure -> configure.sessionFixation( … ))` here in the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/SessionManagementConfigurer.html#sessionFixation(org.springframework.security.config.Customizer)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was putting the `sessionFixation()` at the end. Can you add it as the answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [@toerktumlare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1840146/toerktumlare), you can set the `sessionFixation` in two ways.

```java
.sessionManagement(config ->
    config
        .sessionFixation().none()       // <---- Here
        .invalidSessionUrl("/invalidSession.html")
        .maximumSessions(1)
        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
)
```

or add a `and()` and then configure the `sessionFixation()`

```java
.sessionManagement(config ->
    config
        .invalidSessionUrl("/invalidSession.html")
        .maximumSessions(1)
        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
        .and()
        .sessionFixation().none()      // <---- Here
)
```

Comment: The order is not important, you can set it everywhere in the config. There are more than 2 working orders.

Comment: I wanted to highlight how `sessionFixation` can be configured when other configs are set first, and also when other config follow when `sessionFixation` is set first.